# Reorder/reset column unique id in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I do not know a lot of mysql. I have two tables on same server:

**A.artists**

```
id | artist_name 
--------------------
8  | XXXX      |          
1  | YYYY      |          
5  | ZZZZ      |
```

**A.albums**

```
id | artist_id | album_name
-----------------------------
1 |      5     | Album 1  
2 |      1     | Album 2
3 |      8     | Album 3
```

I want to reorder the `artist_id` column, accordingly, at the same time I want to change `A.artists`'s `id` column from reordered `artist_id` `id`.
Is it possible such a thing? How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: 1.ORDER BY id and 2.ORDER BY artist_id

Comment: You want to change the literal order it's stored in the table or do you want to select items in certain order? If it's the latter you need to show us your query.  It's not clear what you want to change with the ids

Comment: ***Don't*** change the IDs. You *might* want to add a `sort_order` column and play around with that, but you should never need change the ID of an entity; You'll break foreign key relationships, potentially fragment indexes, and *(most of all)* it should never be necessary in a correctly built relational database.

Comment: I have a sql dump and does not exist foreign key. I want the reset id's, then reset connected columns.

Comment: If you are resetting `connected columns` then you are resetting foreign key relationships - even if you have not enforced them with constraints, they exist. You should avoid doing this, the data will function correctly as-is.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand that tables in SQL are unordered. So, you cannot specify an ordering for the table.  You can specify an ordering for a query.

My guess is that you want to join the two tables to get the name with the albums:

```
select al.*, ar.name
from albums al join
     artists ar
     on al.artist_id = ar.id
order by ar.name
```

The way your question is phrased is that you want to re-assign ids.  Normally, this would not be necessary, since the ids exist only to uniquely identify rows.  If you have a good reason for reassigning ids, then modify your question or ask a new question, including the reason.

Comment: @DenemeDenemeAs . . . Can you explain why?  Reassigning ids that are used as foreign keys is highly unusual.